# How do I install xFREERDP 11 on to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rdp

I am looking for a sure fire way of installing  xFREERDP 11 on the Ubuntu 12.04 environment as my attempts have failed so far.

Answer (score 16):

You can install install xFREERDP 11 using a Terminal.

Install the `freerdp-x11` package using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

[Reference](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xfreerdp&searchon=contents)

Command syntax for `freerdp-x11` is:

```
xfreerdp [options] server[:port] [[options] server[:port] ...]
```

[Reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xfreerdp.1.html)

Comment: hello , i have used this command , but cant seem to access the application , i cant find the exe file so to speak to actually run the program from an icon

Comment: also once this command is run should this literally allow me to access the rdp client and use it to connect to servers etc or are further commands needed once the install command has been run.

Comment: you can use the "remmina" package as a GUI front end for it, too

Comment: it's now `apt update; apt install freerdp2-x11` (2019)

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 20.04
in case:

> E: Package 'freerdp-x11' has no installation candidate

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp2-x11
```